# Right-to-left cycle multiplication in Wolfram alpha

Tags: group-theory, permutations, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram alpha carries out cycle multiplication from left-to-right. If the context dictates a right-to-left (function composition) operation, there probably is a way (short of rearranging the order of the operands) to indicate the shift.

Although a command prompt would be greatly appreciated, the fact that I haven't found an answer to this questions in some posts on the topic outside MSE leads me to believe that there may not be one.

> If this is the case, is there a way to get the right-to-left multiplication avoiding careless mistakes in reordering the factors?

For instance, in the case of 2 cycles in $S_5,$ it is pretty easy. Say, the cycle multiplication $(1 2 3 4) (3 4 5) $ entered into Wolfram Alpha as `permutation (1 2 3 4) (3 4 5)` results in:

[image]

But if what we want is right-to-left we only have to swap the cycles, i.e. $(3 4 5)  (1 2 3 4) :$

[image]

However, when more cycles come into play the odds of making a mistake rearranging cycles and its tediousness negate the "double-checking" benefit of using a computer.

Here an example of how it can get clunky: Trying to check a [slight oversight on an otherwise excellent series of lectures](https://youtu.be/AwYCNUF4UE0?t=5m1s), where the right cosets of the subgroup $H=\{(),(12),(34),(12)(34)\}<S_4$ generated by $(13),$ with multiplication from right to left, i.e. $H(13)=\{()(13),(12)(13),(34)(13),(12)(34)(13)\}=\{(13),(132),(143),\color{red}{(1423)}\}$ entails swapping the order from $(12)(34)(13)$ to $(13)(34)(12):$

[image]